# Highcharts Tooltip

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am coding in typescript react js and I have a highstocks graph. The problem I need help with is that I need to show the values on hover on tags (div boxes) above the graph individual to each series plotted within. The values coincide with wherever the cursor is on the graph. Please help me to achieve this.

I am attaching an image for better understanding. The dotted line on the image is where the cursor is at the moment and I want to show the values: [128.32, 49.94, 1.01] instead of '--' next to each tag name: ['Throttle Valve, Posi', 'Mill Hydr. Unit, Gri', 'Water Injection, Pos']. Thanks

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibXmq.png)

Comment: One possible option could be positioning and styling the tooltip [demo1](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/positioner/). Another option is to add an element HTML as in the [demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y5qr2b7t/1/) and display the current value in it. It would be best if you share a simplified example of your case for testing.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying, 
I am currently using setState and displaying the state on the component. The stateChange is done when the user hovers over the graph through the mouseOver event. However, this method is not working

Comment: Example of code for diagnosis, please.

Comment: Hi, hope you're well. I was able to come up with a solution through the plotoptions.series.point.events.click function. On click the value is displayed

Comment: However, it requires me to click on the point and not anywhere on the graph. 
I also found the function that returns an event whenever the area on the graph is clicked through chart.events.click function. 
As stated on the highcharts api - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click - one parameter 'e' is passed to the function. 
e.xAxis[0].value & e.yAxis[0].value return the value of the point where the graph was clicked. However, i need the yAxis value of the Series point that corresponds to the xAxis value. I am also attaching a jsfiddle for further elaboration

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-click/

Comment: As you can see, the coordinates that show on click are of where the cursor was when the click event occured. What I want are the series coordinates that correspond to the click event

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8u5h69e4/3/#&togetherjs=z5BgREyJoP

Answer (score 0):

Inside click events, you can access the nearest point using `this.hoverPoint`.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      click: function() {
          console.log(this.hoverPoint)
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8eym6jwo/

Comment: What if multiple series are plotted and I want to get nearest point of each series?

Comment: Pointed to the nearest point, and catches the same point as the tooltip, [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8eym6jwo/1/).

Comment: I actually have one more question if you don't mind me asking, 
Plotlines in highstocks graph do not seem to appear when there are multiple y-axis'. Do you know why or if you have a solution?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8u5h69e4/3/#&togetherjs=z5BgREyJoP

Comment: This is how Im doing it atm

Comment: [Example plotlines](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/plotlines-acrosspanes/) show correctly, check API references [yAxis.plotLines](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.plotLines).

Comment: I still don't get it. I attached the demo above

Comment: You need to explain in more detail because your example doesn't tell me anything, and the demo shows Highcharts but you are asking about Highstock.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. Appreciate everyone who helped out.
The solution (for getting an onclick point for multiple plotted series) is as follows:

```
this.hoverPoints?.map((item_hoverPoints, index_hoverPoints) => {
 temp_trackValues[index_hoverPoints] = Number(
  item_hoverPoints?.series?.points[this.hoverPoint?.index]?.y
  ).toFixed(3).toString();
});
```

Thanks